# How do I get the three line menu option in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

I have seen the button on Android apps and I was curious if such a feature is available on iOS? I've thought about using a split view controller and then trying to trigger the detail via that button, but I am not sure how I would go about that. In short, I don't know how I would get the detail view controller to slide through the master. [Click here to see what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3ode.png) 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That's not an Apple control, you can either create your own or find a third party library.

Comment: That's called a "hamburger menu".

Comment: Yes you can create a button which look like this

Comment: It is called "Hamburger Menu" and apple has a strong opinion about it: http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/06/30/apple-on-hamburger-menus

Answer (score 1):

You need to add yourself, it's not native option for developer, it's called Hamburger Menu :)

Add your button in view with image you wished [menu image](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/134216/hamburger_lines_menu_icon#size=128). That's it. If you want menu library I recommend to use [LGSideMenuController](https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGSideMenuController)